# React Native - Overlay in Camera

Tags: android, ios, react-native, camera, camera-overlay

I'm developing an app in react native and I will take some pictures.

I need to have a grid over my camera, and when the user take the picture, my app will save the image and the grid together.

Does anyone know how I solve this problem?

Thanks

This link below show exactly I need

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/362327/react-native-overlay-em-camera

Answer (score 6):

I solved this problem using **[react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera)** and **[react-native-view-shot](https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot)** packages.
Inside the RNCamera component, I created my grid with position absolute and to save the picture with grid above, I used the **captureScreen** function from react-native-view-shot package.